# Is there a difference between pd.Series.dt.weekday vs pd.Series.dt.dayofweek?

Tags: python, pandas

I am with time in Pandas and have seen that there are two ways of extracting a Day of Week integer from a timestamp. These are `pd.Series.dt.weekday` and `pd.Series.dt.dayofweek`.

The documentation says that both return: *Series or Index containing integers indicating the day number* where the day of the week with `Monday=0`, `Sunday=6`.

Am I missing something or are these two functions effectively the same?

In the "See Also" section, it does describe the other function as an Alias. Does this answer my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solved your question:

```
 |  dayofweek
 |      The day of the week with Monday=0, Sunday=6.
 |      
 |      Return the day of the week. It is assumed the week starts on
 |      Monday, which is denoted by 0 and ends on Sunday which is denoted
 |      by 6. This method is available on both Series with datetime
 |      values (using the `dt` accessor) or DatetimeIndex.
 |      
 |      Returns
 |      -------
 |      Series or Index
 |          Containing integers indicating the day number.
 |      
 |      See Also
 |      --------
 |      Series.dt.dayofweek : Alias.
 |      Series.dt.weekday : Alias.  # <-- YES IT'S AN ALIAS
 |      Series.dt.day_name : Returns the name of the day of the week.
```

[Source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1423ef0f917220682382d478761bf31315a197ef/pandas/core/arrays/period.py#L440-L441):

```
    dayofweek = day_of_week
    weekday = dayofweek
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming that, it is what I suspected but have been burnt by presumptions too many times